# How to draw trendlines in lightweight-charts with left or right extension?

Tags: lightweight-charts

How to draw lines between any two highs or lows of the candlestick bars to make a slanted trend line that can extend to left or right or both directions?

Extending left or right by creating a custom series manually using y = mx + b formula seems plausible, but a direct straight-forward method would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

to draw diagonal trend line use addLineSeries: https://jsfiddle.net/pv62e9da/5/

```
lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries({
  lastValueVisible: false
});
var tldata = [];
tldata.push({
  time: data[3].time,
  value: data[3].close
});
tldata.push({
  time: data[50].time,
  value: data[50].close
});
lineSeries.setData(tldata);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible right now. `lightweight-charts` doesn't support drawings at all (except workaround for drawing trend line with series with the only 2 points).

We aren't going to add drawing itself to the library, but we thought about extending the API to allow you draw on canvas directly. If you'd like to use drawings, I can suggest you take a look at [charting_library](https://www.tradingview.com/HTML5-stock-forex-bitcoin-charting-library/?feature=technical-analysis-charts).

Comment: What is this charting_library you mention? Any links appreciated

Comment: https://www.tradingview.com/HTML5-stock-forex-bitcoin-charting-library/?feature=technical-analysis-charts

Comment: @timocov There is any way to get charting library for personal use? No company, no public site?