# How to draw line in lightweight-charts or embed code with js code?

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

I need draw line, text, shape and... in chart with javascript code but I can't find anyway for this
I find all setting in for chenge backcolor in website (https://www.tradingview.com) but I can't find draw shape in chart

this image is example:

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwFdm.png)]

this my code :

```
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="main"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSDT/?exchange=BINANCE"
      rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">BTCUSDT chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    widget = new TradingView.widget(
      {
        "autosize": true,
        "symbol": "BINANCE:BTCUSDT",
        "interval": "1",
        "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
        "theme": "dark",
        "style": "1",
        "locale": "en",
        "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
        "enable_publishing": true,
        "withdateranges": true,
        "hide_side_toolbar": false,
        "allow_symbol_change": true,
        "details": true,
        "hotlist": true,
        "calendar": true,
        "container_id": "main"
      }
    );
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To draw a price line with Lightweight Charts you should use the [`createPriceLine`](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/ISeriesApi#createpriceline) method which is part of the ISeriesAPI.

See Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/1349

Comment: Can you help me more with an example because I used this method but it says it doesn't exist

Comment: The method is part of the ISeriesAPI. This is the instance you get when you add a series to the chart. Here is an example: https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/tutorials/how_to/price-line

Answer (score 0):

to draw diagonal trend line like on screenshot use `addLineSeries`: [How to draw trendlines in lightweight-charts with left or right extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62617844/how-to-draw-trendlines-in-lightweight-charts-with-left-or-right-extension/76865382#76865382)